How can I arrange letters into groups of six to have the fewest groups possible?
I'm thinking about making a toy to recreate the wordle (NYT game) experience. There's a list of 2300+ valid wordle words, which use a mix of letters. Sometimes those words may have duplicates of the same letter.
If I want to turn this into a physical toy, I'd need a bunch of cubes, each with 6 different letters on them, so that I could choose 5 of those and spell my word.
How would I work out how many cubes I would need, and what letters to put on each cube, in order to be able to have the fewest cubes possible?

Is ignoring the word list (ie. QQXZQ is a valid word) acceptable? If so, you might be able to get a simple minimal solution. If not, you'll need a computer to figure it out. Also, note that since you're making a product, this is not only a combinatorics problem, but also a user experience one; I imagine people would be much happier with your toy with 5 "vowel cubes" rather than having to search through all the cubes to find the letter(s) they want.

I reckon ignoring the full word list is fine, and would make it more fun

Also, if this is to be a commercial product, you should probably consider that an officially licensed product already exists. If you're 3d-printing this for friends & family it's probably fine

Yeah, I wasn't intending to go commercial with it, more a toy for my own use!

I assume that you want to be able to form each word one at a time.  You can solve the problem via integer linear programming.  For the $2315$-word list, a lower bound turns out to be $10$ cubes, and an upper bound is $13$ cubes:
A B E G L P
A E F G O X
A E H I O U
A E I O U Y
A L N R S T
B F G M N P
B L N P Y Z
C D L R S T
C H K S V W
C J K S U W
D H M R T V
D I M O R T
F N Q X Y Z

Note that one cube (the fourth one) contains only the vowels.  I did not impose this as a constraint, and it just fell out naturally.

To see that $10$ is a lower bound, consider the maximum number of times that each letter appears in a word:
A 2 
B 3 
C 2 
D 3 
E 3 
F 3 
G 2 
H 2 
I 2 
J 1 
K 2 
L 2 
M 3 
N 3 
O 2 
P 3 
Q 1 
R 3 
S 3 
T 3 
U 2 
V 2 
W 2 
X 1 
Y 2 
Z 2 

These maximum values sum to $59$, so we need at least $\lceil 59/6\rceil = 10$ cubes.  It turns out that $10$ is achievable and hence optimal:
A B H I R U
A E O T U Z
B C M N P W
B H M N S Z
C G P R T W
D E I K L M
D F K T V Y
D F Q R S X
E G J N S Y
F L O P U V

If you prefer the aesthetics of having an all-vowel cube, you can use the following $10$ cubes instead:
A B C D G U
A E I O U Y
A L M N P V
B G H K S Z
B L M S T W
C E F H J R
D F K O Q V
D I M P R W
E N P S T X
F N R T Y Z


By request, here is SAS code:
filename myurl url 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Radcliffe/4bf75c1f52a610779c9c14859461a376/raw/dc4b740afdf04e6d507982bdf2cbc02f90ce3727/wordle-entropy.csv';

data words;
   infile myurl dlm=',' firstobs=2;
   input row_no word $ entropy common;
   word = upcase(word);
   if common = 1;
run;

proc optmodel;
   set <str> WORDS;
   read data words into WORDS=[word];
   set LETTERS = setof {k in 65..65+26-1} byte(k);
   num numPositions = 5;
   set POSITIONS = 1..numPositions;
   num numCubes = 10;
   set CUBES = 1..numCubes;

   var IsCube {CUBES} binary;
   var IsCubeLetter {CUBES, LETTERS} binary;
   var IsWordPositionCube {WORDS, POSITIONS, CUBES} binary;

   min Objective = sum {c in CUBES} IsCube[c];

   con Cover {w in WORDS, p in POSITIONS}:
      sum {c in CUBES} IsWordPositionCube[w,p,c] >= 1;
   con SixLettersPerCube {c in CUBES}:
      sum {l in LETTERS} IsCubeLetter[c,l] = 6*IsCube[c];
   con DistinctCubesPerWord {w in WORDS, c in CUBES}:
      sum {p in POSITIONS} IsWordPositionCube[w,p,c] <= IsCube[c];
   con Indicator {w in WORDS, p in POSITIONS, c in CUBES}:
      IsWordPositionCube[w,p,c] <= IsCubeLetter[c,char(w,p)];

   solve;

   for {c in CUBES: IsCube[c].sol > 0.5} do;
      put c @;
      for {l in LETTERS: IsCubeLetter[c,l].sol > 0.5} put l @;
      put;
   end;
   num sol {WORDS, POSITIONS};
   for {w in WORDS, p in POSITIONS, c in CUBES: IsWordPositionCube[w,p,c].sol > 0.5} sol[w,p] = c;
   print sol;
quit;


Incredible, thanks so much. I figured that 10 would be the lower bound, but wasn't sure how to categorize the problem. Much appreciated!

I would absolutely love to know how you managed to arrive at this answer? Any chance you'd share the code?

Note that the below applies to the cubes needed to make one word; since in the game Wordle you make up to six such words, you will likely need six times as many cubes as described here.
First of all, a lower bound can be found on the number of cubes by calculating the required number of faces. There are 26 letters, each of which needs to appear on 5 faces, so we have at least
$$\left\lceil\frac{5\cdot26}{6}\right\rceil=22 {\rm\ cubes}$$
This lower bound can be accomplished by partitioning the alphabet into two groups of 6 and two groups of 7. The groups of 6 can be accomplished by making 5 identical cubes with one letter on each face. The groups of 7 can be accomplished by making 6 cubes with one of the seven letters missing on each.
In addition to satisfying the property that the dice can make all words, this arrangement also has the property that you can spell any word by choosing any cube with the desired letter, without blocking yourself.
One possible arrangement of the cubes is shown below:
AEIOUY
AEIOUY
AEIOUY
AEIOUY
AEIOUY

BCDFGH
BCDFGH
BCDFGH
BCDFGH
BCDFGH

JKLMNP
JKLMNQ
JKLMPQ
JKLNPQ
JKMNPQ
JLMNPQ

RSTVWX
RSTVWZ
RSTVXZ
RSTWXZ
RSVWXZ
RTVWXZ

